# Number of followers of my organization - Linkedin API

Tags: permissions, linkedin-api

I've got an App created and verified by my company. I want to get the number of followers of the company.

I am trying to do the following query:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityFollowerStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn_li_organization:XXXXXXXX
```

But I get the error:

> {
>       "serviceErrorCode": 100,
>       "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET-organizationalEntity /organizationalEntityFollowerStatistics",
>       "status": 403
>   }

I've tried to do some other queries but I have only got data for the basic query:

```
 https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me
```

The permissions of the App are the following:

- r_emailaddress
- r_ads
- r_basicprofile
- r_liteprofile
- r_ads_reporting
- r_organization_social
- r_1st_connections_size
- rw_organization_admin
- rw_ads
- w_organization_social
- w_member_social

What else do I need to extract the followers of my organization? I am the administrator of the organization account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the answer.

When I created the authorization code, I did not asked for the proper permissions through the scope parameter.

I have created the authorization code again and now I get results from the query.